# how to validate against a schema in Vala

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, vala

I'm want to parse a xml file into a Xml.Doc object and validate it against a schema file in Vala. Does Vala provide this functionality? I've searched http://valadoc.org, but I cannot find anything.

I would expect the following C functions to be available in Vala:

1. xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr parser_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt(schema_doc);
2. xmlSchemaPtr schema = xmlSchemaParse(parser_ctxt);
3. xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr valid_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);

I can only find the third one, SchemaValidCtxt mentioned in valadoc, but the page is virtually blank. Is this a valid usable class?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm want to parse a xml file into a Xml.Doc object and validate it against a schema file in Vala. Does Vala provide this functionality? I've searched http://valadoc.org, but I cannot find anything.

If you're looking for the Vala equivalent of a C function in libxml you can just search [libxml-2.0.vapi](http://git.gnome.org/browse/vala/tree/vapi/libxml-2.0.vapi) and look for the cname.  Valadoc.org does not currently allow you to search for C symbols, though AFAIK the feature is planned.

> I would expect the following C functions to be available in Vala:
>
> 1. xmlSchemaParserCtxtPtr parser_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt(schema_doc);
> 2. xmlSchemaPtr schema = xmlSchemaParse(parser_ctxt);
> 3. xmlSchemaValidCtxtPtr valid_ctxt = xmlSchemaNewValidCtxt(schema);

The libxml-2.0 Vala bindings are pretty incomplete and nobody wants to work on them since the C API is really messy.  Usually what ends up happening is someone comes along and needs something specific so they add it and submit a patch.  Apparently you're the first person to need support for XML Schemas.

xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt is bound as [Xml.ParserCtxt.ParserCtxt.create_doc](http://valadoc.org/libxml-2.0/Xml.ParserCtxt.ParserCtxt.create_doc.html).  The other two functions are not currently bound, though it's not very difficult to bind them.  Adding something like this (completely untested) to the libxml-2.0 VAPI should do the trick:

```
    [Compact]
    [CCode (cname = "xmlSchema", free_function = "xmlSchemaFree", cheader_filename = "libxml/xmlschemas.h")]
    public class Schema {
        [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaDump", instance_pos = -1)]
        public void dump (GLib.FileStream output);
    }

    [Compact]
    [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaParserCtxt", free_function = "xmlSchemaFreeParserCtxt", cheader_filename = "libxml/xmlschemas.h")]
    public class SchemaParserCtxt {
        [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaNewParserCtxt")]
        public SchemaParserCtxt (string URL);
        [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaNewDocParserCtxt")]
        public SchemaParserCtxt.from_doc (Xml.Doc doc);
        [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaNewMemParserCtxt")]
        public SchemaParserCtxt.from_buffer (uint8[] buffer);
        [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaParse")]
        public Xml.Schema parse ();
    }

    [Compact]
    [CCode (cname = "xmlSchemaValidCtxt", free_function = "xmlSchemaFreeValidCtxt", cheader_filename = "libxml/xmlschemas.h")]
    public class SchemaValidCtxt {
        public SchemaValidCtxt (Xml.Schema schema);
    }
```

> I can only find the third one, SchemaValidCtxt mentioned in valadoc, but the page is virtually blank. Is this a valid usable class?

It is just an empty shell right now--none of the methods are bound.  Luckily, adding bindings is pretty easy.